# Should private inheritance be used when there are no virtuals?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, encapsulation

In C++, if I have a class `Base` which is a private base class of `Derived` but `Base` has no virtual functions, would it be cleaner to instead replace having inheritance with encapsulation in class `Encapsulate`? I imagine the only benefit to inheritance in this case would be that the base class can be accessed directly in the derived class as opposed to through `memberVariable`. Is one or the other practice considered better, or is it more of a personal style question?

```
class Base {
  public:
    void privateWork();
    // No virtual member functions here.
};

class Derived : Base {
  public:
    void doSomething() {
      privateWork();
    }
};

class Encapsulate {
    Base memberVariable;

  public:
    void doSomething() {
      memberVariable.privateWork()
    }
};
```

Comment: Throw GoF Design Patterns out of the window and start coding... :)

Comment: Shouldn't you have at least a virtual destructor?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: If inheritance is private, there is no way you can destroy a derived through a base pointer anyway. So I'd say not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that inheritance models "Liskov substitution": Foo is a Bar if and only if you can pass a Foo variable to every function expecting a Bar. Private inheritance does not model this. It models composition (Foo is implemented in terms of Bar).

Now, you should pretty much always use the second version, since it is simpler and expresses the intent better: it is less confusing for people who don't know about it.

However, sometimes, private inheritance is handy:

```
class FooCollection : std::vector<Foo>
{
public:
    FooCollection(size_t n) : std::vector<Foo>(n) {};

    using std::vector<Foo>::begin;
    using std::vector<Foo>::end;
    using std::vector<Foo>::operator[];
};
```

This allows you to reuse some of the functionality of `vector` without having to forward manually the 2 versions (const + non const) of begin, end, and `operator[]`.

In this case, you don't have polymorphism at all: this is not inheritance, this is composition is disguise; there is no way you can use a `FooCollection` as a vector. In particular, you don't need a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no `virtual` functions, then inheritance should not be used in OO. Note this does not mean that it must not be used, there are a few (limited) cases where you might need to (ab)use inheritance for other purposes than OO.

Comment: Occasionally private inheritance is fine for "implemented in terms of" relationships I believe.

Comment: @MarkB: inheritance is the most abused feature. As a general rule of thumb, inheritance is about code reuse but in the opposite direction that most people consider: Inheritance should be use so that code that works with your base will work with your new type (as opposed to abusing inheritance to reuse the functionality in your base). A class with no virtual functions (hand waving: i.e. assuming no static polymorphism) should not be derived: existing code that takes a `Base` object will not be able to do new things by taking a `Derived` reference

Comment: @MarkB: Consider a framework that has a timer class on which you can register to be notified. The framework requires a particular interface to register into the timer, (say `Notifiable`). Now consider that you want to offer a periodic timer in your application for which the exact framework in use is just an implementation detail. Then you would use private inheritance for "implemented in terms of", that is: from the client point of view your class is not an instance of `Notifiable`, but internally that is how you are implemented.

Comment: Private inheritance does not model is-a. Private inheritance is nothing more than a sometimes convenient way to express composition. The rule of thumb is "don't use it unless it makes you write a hell lot less code" (eg. you can make a good use of the `using` directive). Inheriting privately from `std::vector` and `using` a few members of vector in your class is sometimes convenient.

Comment: @AlexandreC. This deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: That falls under the *(ab)use inheritance for other purposes than OO* (i.e. it is not a sound OO approach, although it might make sense due to limitations in the language --metaprogramming tricks-- or simpler syntax)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'd go further and simply say that private inheritance is not inheritance at all for OO considerations (except perhaps at class scope, but there `dynamic_cast` doesn't work, so it's a little crippled). Where you are perfectly right is that inheritance must provide the substitution principle. Where I don't follow you is about polymorphism: it may make sense to have non polymorphic inheritance relationships, provided the LSP is verified (it wouldn't be too useful, but it makes sense).

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Precisely because of LSP (ignoring templates): If you inherit from a base type that has no virtuals (i.e. not polymorphic), then you cannot perform the substitution in LSP: you can pass a pointer to the derived type as if it was a base type, but that will not behave as a derived object, but as a base (trivially meeting the LSP letter, if not the spirit). From my point of view, the importance is that you can *override* parts of the behavior, without that ability, composition is a less coupling relationship.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Of course. But a derived class need not override the base class behavior. It may just add its own, and this is what I implied by "it makes sense".